# Organizing methods within classes in a simulation of a dice game

Tags: java, syntax, brackets

I had help writing this program as a simulation of a dice game, but I can't seem to get it to run because of the syntax/bracket situation.  I think I am having trouble organizing my methods within the classes. Any tips?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class diceGame 
{
    private class DiceRoll
    {
        public static Random rng = new Random();
        private int a, b, c; //rolls

        public DiceRoll()
        {
            this.a = rng.nextInt(6);
            this.b = rng.nextInt(6);
            this.c = rng.nextInt(6);
        }

        public int getScore()
        {
            if (a ==6 && b == 6 && c ==6)
            {
                return 500;
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
            }
            else if ((a == 6 && b == 6 && b != c) || (b == 6 && c == 6 && c !=a))
            {
                return 100;
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled two 6s! You just earned 100 points!!");
            }
            else if ((a == b && b != c) || (b == c && c !=a))
            {
                return 50;
                System.out.println("Congratulations! You just earned 50 points!!");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Nice Try!");
            }
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("Rolled a %d, %d, and %d", a, b, c);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        DiceRoll d; 
        while (true)
        {
            d = new DiceRoll();
            d.getScore();        // gives you how much to change the player score
        }
        // finish client
    }
}
}
```

Comment: /me sighs... Can you __Please__ format your code? Please?

Comment: There is an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: You should use an IDE like eclipse to help you fix errors.

Comment: Just for future reference, run your code through a debugger before posting on here

Comment: You could open your .java file from netbeans or other source code editing tool and do Source->Format. It would arrange the braces and format the code for you to be more readable. :) Or just post your java source to http://codebeautify.org/javaviewer and press button "Beautify" :)

Answer (score 2):

One look:

```
if (a ==6 && b == 6 && c ==6){
  return 500;
  System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!"); //This is the error!
}
```

Once you return from a method, any other code will not be run and it will cause a compile error. I think this is what you want:

```
if (a ==6 && b == 6 && c ==6) {
  System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
  return 500;
}
```

Also, look at this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  DiceRoll d;
  while (true) {
    d = new DiceRoll();
    d.getScore(); // gives you how much to change the player score
  } // finish client
}
}
} //Extra
```

Remove the curly brace marked "Extra".

Also, the Random `rng` is static, but it is declared in a non-static class.

Change it to `private static class DiceRoll`

Your `getScore()` method is borked; It does not return anything.

```
    public int getScore() {
        if (a == 6 && b == 6 && c == 6) {
            return 500;
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
        } else if ((a == 6 && b == 6 && b != c) || (b == 6 && c == 6 && c != a)) {
            return 100;
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled two 6s! You just earned 100 points!!");
        } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (b == c && c != a)) {
            return 50;
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You just earned 50 points!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nice Try!");
            //Wut no return?
        }
    }
```

You might want:

```
  public int getScore() {
    if (a == 6 && b == 6 && c == 6) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
      return 500;
    } else if ((a == 6 && b == 6 && b != c) || (b == 6 && c == 6 && c != a)) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled two 6s! You just earned 100 points!!");
      return 100;
    } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (b == c && c != a)) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You just earned 50 points!!");
      return 50;
    } else {
      System.out.println("Nice Try!");
      return -1;
    }
  }
```

And its a good idea to call your `diceGame` class `DiceGame`

Comment: This fix alone doesn't make the dice running .

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code

1. There are no return statements for some methods
2. There are few Sysout's after return (which makes the code unreachable)
3. The concept of Parent class Inner class is wrong. In an inner class , speaking of static, you can have only constants which are both static and final.
4. The bracketing is wrong.

The below code would work and only terminate when all the dices are rolled 6.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class diceGame {
    private class DiceRoll {
        public Random rng = new Random();
        private int a, b, c; // rolls

        public DiceRoll() {
            this.a = rng.nextInt(6);
            this.b = rng.nextInt(6);
            this.c = rng.nextInt(6);
        }

        public int getScore() {
            if (a == 6 && b == 6 && c == 6) {
                System.out
                        .println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
                return 500;

            } else if ((a == 6 && b == 6 && b != c)
                    || (b == 6 && c == 6 && c != a)) {
                System.out
                        .println("Congratulations! You rolled two 6s! You just earned 100 points!!");
                return 100;

            } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (b == c && c != a)) {
                System.out
                        .println("Congratulations! You just earned 50 points!!");
                return 50;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Nice Try!");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Rolled a %d, %d, and %d", a, b, c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DiceRoll d;
        while (true) {
            d = new diceGame().new DiceRoll();
            if (d.getScore() == 500) { // gives you how much to change the player score

                break;
            }

        }
        // finish client
    }
}
```

You would need to fix all these for the dice to roll.

Comment: Not all methods need to return! If you don't return, it will just run all the code until the method ends

Answer (score 1):

There is quite few problems with your code. The first one is idea about using inner class, so that inner class should go out. All methods can go to outer class. Placing rolling into constructor makes game boring, a, b and c will stay the same for lifetime of instance or forces you to create new instance for each roll. Really bad design decision. I would move that into `getScore`.
Finally `while(true)` will go on forever and you will have to kill program to stop it. Here is your code and check scoring logic, I do not know rules:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class diceGame {
  public static Random rng = new Random();
  private int a, b, c; //rolls
  public int getScore() {
    this.a = 1 + rng.nextInt(5);
    this.b = 1 + rng.nextInt(5);
    this.c = 1 + rng.nextInt(5);
    if (a == 6 && b == 6 && c == 6) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled three 6s! You just earned 500 points!!");
      return 500;
    } else if ((a == 6 && b == 6 && b != c) || (b == 6 && c == 6 && c != a)) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You rolled two 6s! You just earned 100 points!!");
      return 100;
    } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (b == c && c != a) || (a == c && b != a)) {
      System.out.println("Congratulations! You just earned 50 points!!");
      return 50;

    } else {
      System.out.println("Nice Try!");
      return 0;
    }
  }
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Rolled a %d, %d, and %d", a, b, c);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    diceGame d = new diceGame();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      System.out.println(d.getScore());
      System.out.println(d.toString());
    }
  }
}
```